# Assigning ID to an image in canvas (HTML5)

Tags: jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have written a code in HTML5 to load an image into a canvas. Its as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function ()
        {
            var canvas1 = document.getElementById("cvs1");
            var canvas2 = document.getElementById("cvs2");
            var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
            var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
            var imageXY  = {x: 50, y: 50};



            // Load the image on canvas1 initially and set the state up with some defaults

            state = {}
            state.dragging     = false;
            state.canvas       = document.getElementById("cvs2");
            state.image        =  new Image();
            state.image.src    = 'pick.jpg';
            //state.image.id       = 'img1';
            state.offsetX      = 0;
            state.offsetY      = 0;

            state.image.onload = function ()
            {
                Draw();
            }


             // This draws the image to the canvas

            function Draw ()
            {
                //Clear both canvas first
                context1.clearRect(0,0,canvas1.width,canvas1.height);
                context2.clearRect(0,0,canvas2.width,canvas2.height);

                //Draw a red rectangle around the image
                if (state && state.dragging) {
                    state.canvas.getContext('2d').strokeStyle = 'red';
                    state.canvas.getContext('2d').strokeRect(imageXY.x - 2.5,
                                                             imageXY.y - 2.5,
                                                             state.image.width + 5,
                                                             state.image.height + 5);
                }

                // Now draw the image
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(state.image, imageXY.x, imageXY.y);
            }            
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        canvas
        {
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>

<body>

    <canvas id="cvs1" width="150" height="600" style="float: left">[No canvas support]</canvas>
    <canvas id="cvs2" width="600" height="600" style="float: left; margin-left: 10px">[No canvas support]</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

The properties of the state can be set as aforementioned. But, I want to use this image for various events through JQuery. I tried to use "state.image.id = 'img1';" (Which has been commented), but its not working.

Can somebody help me out in adding an id for the image dynamically to the canvas image ?? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but if you are drawing anything into HTML5 Canvas it is just been drawn depending upon the coordinates. It is not a DOM element which gets created, so you cannot give it any id.
Ids can only be given to the elements.

Comment: Is it impossible or, is there any workaround for that ? In case there is any workarounds, it will be great. Please let me know.

Comment: I think it is not possible. You can also see the same if you will see the source of the page which got rendered on the browser, there will be no such element generated for that image to which we can provide Id to...

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code doesn't appear to include anything to demonstrate the problem.

FWIW, I don't think you can query the DOM for the image if it isn't actually attached to the DOM.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        state = {}
        state.dragging     = false;
        state.canvas       = document.getElementById("cvs");
        state.image        =  new Image();
        state.image.src    = 'pick.jpg';
        state.image.id       = 'pickimage';

        state.image.onload = function ()
        {
            Draw();
        }

        function Draw ()
        {
            var ctx = state.canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.clearRect(0,0,state.canvas.width,state.canvas.height);

            // this fails
            if ( $( "#pickimage" ).length ) {
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage( $( "#pickimage" )[0], 0, 0 );
            }

            // so does this
            if ( document.getElementById("pickimage") ) {
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage( document.getElementById("pickimage"), 0, 256 );
            }

            state.canvas.appendChild( state.image );

            // but this works
            if ( $( "#pickimage" ).length ) {
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage( $( "#pickimage" )[0], 256, 0 );
            }

            // and so does this
            if ( document.getElementById("pickimage") ) {
                state.canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage( document.getElementById("pickimage"), 256, 256 );
            }

        }            
    }
</script>
<style>
    canvas
    {
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
</style>
```

```
<canvas id="cvs" width="512" height="512" >[No canvas support]</canvas>
```